# SQLServer Get Results Where Value Is Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have an SQL server database that I am querying and I only want to get the information when a specific row is null. I used a where statement such as:

```
WHERE database.foobar = NULL
```

and it does not return anything. However, I know that there is at least one result because I created an instance in the database where 'foobar' is equal to null. If I take out the where statement it shows data so I know it is not the rest of the query.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct syntax is WHERE database.foobar IS NULL.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx for more info

Answer (score 3):

Comparison to NULL will be false every time.  You want to use IS NULL instead.

```
x =  NULL      -- always false
x <> NULL      -- always false

x IS NULL      -- these do what you want
x IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: -1 Comparison to NULL will be UNKNOWN with the exceptions `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Read [Testing for Null Values](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_programming_Hacks_-_Testing_for_Null_Values), you need IS NULL not = NULL

Answer (score 1):

Is it an SQL Server database?
If so, use `IS NULL` instead of making the comparison ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933227(SQL.80).aspx)).