# How to use if condition with left join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have below Table which is connected with each other like**

```
Info_Table -> RoomGuests_Table -> ChildAge_Table
```

**These are Tables**

```
        Info_Table          
+---------------------------+
|   ID      |  Name | Rooms |
+---------------------------+
|   INFO1   |   ABC |   2   |
|   INFO2   |   DEF |   1   |
|   INFO3   |   GHI |   3   |
+---------------------------+


           RoomGuests_Table     
+-----------------------------------+   
|   ID  |   R_ID    | Adult | Child |
+-----------------------------------+   
|   RG1 |   INFO1   |   2   |   2   |
|   RG2 |   INFO1   |   3   |   0   |
|   RG3 |   INFO2   |   2   |   1   |
|   RG4 |   INFO3   |   2   |   1   |
|   RG5 |   INFO3   |   2   |   2   |
|   RG6 |   INFO3   |   2   |   1   |
+-----------------------------------+


      ChildAge_Table                        
+-----------------------+   
|   ID  | R_ID  |   Age |
+-----------------------+   
|   CA1 |   RG1 |   4   |
|   CA2 |   RG1 |   5   |
|   CA3 |   RG3 |   2   |
|   CA4 |   RG4 |   7   |
|   CA5 |   RG5 |   1   |
|   CA6 |   RG5 |   5   |
|   CA7 |   RG6 |   3   |
+-----------------------+
```

***I Want Result like this***

If Info_Table's `ID  =  'INFO3';`
Then result should be show like this.

```
                                    Result                              
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   ID      | Name  | Rooms |                           RoomGuests                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   INFO3   |   GHI |   3   | [{ "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"1", "ChildAge":[7] },           |
|           |       |       |  { "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"2", "ChildAge":[1,5] },         |
|           |       |       |  { "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"1", "ChildAge":[3] }]           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I have tried below code and works.**

```
SELECT i.ID, i.name,i.rooms, RG.RoomGuests
FROM Info_Table i 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        R.ID, R.R_ID AS RG_ID,      
        CONCAT(
            '[',
                GROUP_CONCAT( 
                    CONCAT(
                        '{
                            \"NoOfAdults\":\"', Adult,'\",
                            \"NoOfChild\":\"', Child,'\",
                            \"ChildAge\":', CA.ChildAge,'
                        }'
                    ) 
                ),
            ']'
        ) AS RoomGuests 

    FROM RoomGuests_Table R

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            C.R_ID AS CA_ID, 
            CONCAT(
                '[',
                    GROUP_CONCAT( Age SEPARATOR ','),
                ']'
            ) AS ChildAge
        FROM ChildAge_Table C
        GROUP BY CA_ID
    ) CA ON CA.CA_ID = R.ID)

    GROUP BY RG_ID

) RG ON RG.RG_ID = i.ID
WHERE i.ID = 'INFO3';
```

**but in below condition is not working**

IF Record like this

```
        Info_Table          
+---------------------------+
|   ID      |  Name | Rooms |
+---------------------------+
|   INFO3   |   GHI |   3   |
+---------------------------+


           RoomGuests_Table     
+-----------------------------------+   
|   ID  |   R_ID    | Adult | Child |
+-----------------------------------+   
|   RG4 |   INFO3   |   2   |   0   |
|   RG5 |   INFO3   |   2   |   2   |
|   RG6 |   INFO3   |   2   |   1   |
+-----------------------------------+


      ChildAge_Table                        
+-----------------------+   
|   ID  | R_ID  |   Age |
+-----------------------+   
|   CA5 |   RG5 |   1   |
|   CA6 |   RG5 |   5   |
|   CA7 |   RG6 |   3   |
+-----------------------+
```

As you can see `RoomGuests_Table` 's  `RG4` has no child mean it has `0` value so in this condition it should show result like this

```
                                Result                              
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   ID      | Name  | Rooms |                           RoomGuests                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   INFO3   |   GHI |   3   | [{ "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"0", "ChildAge":[] },            |
|           |       |       |  { "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"2", "ChildAge":[1,5] },         |
|           |       |       |  { "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"1", "ChildAge":[3] }]           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

***But is showing like this***

```
                                    Result                              
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   ID      | Name  | Rooms |                           RoomGuests                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   INFO3   |   GHI |   3   | [{ "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"2", "ChildAge":[1,5] },         |
|           |       |       |  { "NoOfAdults":"2", "NoOfChild":"1", "ChildAge":[3] }]           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`ChildAge_Table` has no record of `RG4` so how to my desire result or 
is there any way to check if `CA.ChildAge` = `null` then put there `'[]'`

Comment: use case, when null then add [] else your code.

Comment: If Info_Table's ID  =  'INFO3', isnt the name should be "GHI"?

Comment: @Pirate how to do that i have tried this `IF(CA.ChildAge = NULL,'[]',CA.ChildAge)`

Comment: @jophab i have edit the post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try protecting that `CA.ChildAge` with an `IFNULL` like so:

```
...CONCAT(
          '{\"NoOfAdults\":\"', Adult,'\",
            \"NoOfChild\":\"',  Child,'\",
            \"ChildAge\":',     IFNULL(CA.ChildAge, '[]'),'}'
         )...
```

The problem is that `C.ChildAge` is absent for 'RG4' (which you know) and thus is LEFT JOINed to `RoomGuests_Table` as a NULL `CA.ChildAge`.  This NULL makes the inner `CONCAT('{...}')` NULL as well, but [NULLs are filtered out by `GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), meaning the outer `CONCAT('[...]')` won't see it.

Here's full, working SQL:

```
   SELECT i.ID, i.name,i.rooms, RG.RoomGuests
     FROM Info_Table i 
LEFT JOIN (   SELECT R.ID, R.R_ID AS RG_ID,      
                     CONCAT('[',
                            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{\"NoOfAdults\":\"', Adult,'\",\n',
                                                 '\"NoOfChild\":\"',  Child,'\",\n',
                                                 '\"ChildAge\":',     IFNULL(CA.ChildAge, '[]'),'}')),
                            ']')
                       AS RoomGuests 
                FROM RoomGuests_Table R
           LEFT JOIN (  SELECT C.R_ID AS CA_ID, 
                               CONCAT('[',
                                      GROUP_CONCAT( Age SEPARATOR ','),
                                      ']') AS ChildAge
                          FROM ChildAge_Table C
                      GROUP BY CA_ID) CA
                  ON CA.CA_ID = R.ID) RG
       ON RG.RG_ID = i.ID
    WHERE i.ID = 'INFO3'
 GROUP BY RG_ID;
```

Comment: i have tried this why its not working `IF(CA.ChildAge = NULL,'[]',CA.ChildAge)`,

Comment: @User97798, NULL and the = operator don't do what you want. Search this site for more information.

Comment: which site i didn't get

Comment: @User97798, _this_ site, stackoverflow.com  For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28922/132382).

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches; I have not verified either one:

Plan A:  Use parentheses to say either

```
FROM ... LEFT JOIN ( ... LEFT JOIN ... )
```

or

```
FROM ( ... LEFT JOIN  ... ) LEFT JOIN ...
```

(I don't know which way is the default; I suspect the default is causing you trouble.

Plan B:  Get rid of the second left join.  Replace `CA.ChildAge` by the `SELECT` that makes up the that second join.  (Be sure to parenthesize it.)